# Mean absolute relative error as loss function in tensorflow (regression problem)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, loss-function

I am solving a regression problem using neural network. 
My target output ranges from 10-2 to 10-7. After running a lot of cases I was wondering if the mean squared error loss function can be replaced by a loss function which considers mean absolute relative error. I searched the tensorflow website and found the metric - `tf.metrics.mean_relative_error` but couldn't find anything under tf.losses. Is there any way to implement a loss function which uses relative error within tensorflow?

Answer (score 3):

> Almost in all tensorflow tutorials they use custom functions.

For example in the very [beginning tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/) they write a custom function, which
sums the squares of the deltas between the current model and the provided data

```
squared_deltas = tf.square(linear_model - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
```

As you see it is not that hard at all: you just need to encode your function in a tensor-format and use their basic functions.

*Note:* Just as a little bonus, you might want to think about normalizing your inputs and expected outputs in a more suitable range e.g. [-0.5, 0.5] which works better for a handful of activation functions which otherwise need to work in a saturated area.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried both min max and robust scale transformations on my target values ( which ranges from 10-2 to 10-7). I am also trying to use log transformation on my target variable to see if this provides better results. However, I notice that there is an unavoidable error added, if I use np.log to transform and thereafter np.exp to inverse-transform. Is there any readily available function in sklearn/python to do logarithmic transformation?

Comment: @Lipi I would have to search for that, maybe it helps you to pose this as a new question on SO.